# Last activity of user

Tags: ios, swift, xmpp, xmppframework

i am working with xmpp framework iOS library for my chat application, getting some issue regarding last activity of user it gives "forbidden" error

here it is my code to get user last activity

```
let senderJID = XMPPJID.init(string:detailVC.bareJidStr)   
let lastAcivity = appDelegate.lastActivity?.sendQuery(to: senderJID, withTimeout: XMPPStreamTimeoutNone)
print(lastAcivity as Any)

public func xmppLastActivity(_ sender: XMPPLastActivity!, didReceiveResponse response: XMPPIQ!) {

 // Extract the seconds from response IQ
  let time = response.lastActivitySeconds()
  print("time in seconds \(time)")
  print("response \(response))")}

 error:-> <error code="403" type="auth"><forbidden xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></forbidden></error>
```

Comment: You need to pass Authentication parameter.

Comment: Thanks, but how to pass parameters in this ? can i have any example

Comment: @Bucket Did you get any solution?

Comment: @Bucket Have you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

User need to be in rosters and authorized to see the other user presence. This is explained in Last Activity XEP: http://www.xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0012.html#online

> if the requesting entity is not authorized to view the user's presence
>   information (normally via a presence subscription as defined in XMPP
>   IM), the user's server MUST NOT deliver the IQ-get to an available
>   resource but instead MUST return a  error in response to
>   the last activity request.

Comment: How can I subscribe presence?